pixelated fonts in Adobe Illustrator Mac OS X
disclaimer: Adobe Ai noob
Does Ai treats it non-vector or smth like this? How can I change it?
font is fine, works in other programs without issue

also after saving and previewing the .ai file in Mac OS X default Preview font looks sharp vector as expected.


Beside the file name (top left) of the document window, I can see you are in CPU Pixel Preview.

This will display everything on-screen as pixels. You can switch it off if you don't want to see pixels.
The toggle for Pixel Preview is Opt+Cmd+Y on Mac, or Alt+Ctrl+Y on Windows. I assume you may have just accidentally applied this.  Hit it again to switch it off.
Also note that at 300% zoom, you will see individual pixels when in pixel preview. This is normal and nothing is wrong here. To view a pixel image (a raster image) as it will appear on-screen, eg. in a browser, you shouldn't zoom in more than 100%.

Good catch. ...

it did the trick! thanks!

With the lines in your app screenshot I can only assume you are in editing mode of some sort.. text editing, transforming, something.
When editing objects Illustrator will often use a low resolution proxy preview in order to speed up screen redraw. But when you commit the edit, things should be redrawn and back to standard quality.
You're also zoomed in 300% in Illustrator... and not in Preview.
